# How to make the Select Box Value selected to specific value "ABC" when new row is being added to table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a new row added to table with a buttton click and  we have select element for each row 
and with name "code[]".I have to make the value "ABC"  as selected  when a new row is being added to the table

```
alert($('#mytabl tr:last :input').find('input[name="code[]"]').children($('option[value=ABC]')).attr('selected','selected'));

with the above statement no Effect is being done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your selector is overly complicated, and not selecting a `<select>` element, but looking for a `<input>` inside a [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) currently, try this instead:

```
$('#mytabl tr:last select[name="code[]"]').val('ABC');
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `[]` characters. :o) EDIT: Maybe I'm wrong about that. It seems to work in a test, but the docs seem to say it is necessary.